# How to assign member function pointer to non-member function pointer?

Tags: c++, boost-bind

How to assign member function pointer to non-member function pointer?

I have this library API function:

```
int pfring_loop(pfring *ring, pfringProcesssPacket looper,
        const u_char *user_bytes, u_int8_t wait_for_packet);
```

API defined function pointer:

```
typedef void (*pfringProcesssPacket)(const struct pfring_pkthdr *h, const u_char *p, const u_char *user_bytes);
```

My member function:

```
template<class DERIVED> void pf_ring_impl<DERIVED>::pf_ring_packet_handler(const struct pfring_pkthdr *h, const u_char *p, const u_char *user_bytes)
```

How I call but compile error

```
pfring_loop(pd_, boost::bind(reinterpret_cast<pfringProcesssPacket>(&pf_ring_impl<DERIVED>::pf_ring_packet_handler), this, _1, _2, _3), (u_char*) NULL, wait_for_packet_);
```

Comment: You have to use a freestanding function as callback.

Comment: find similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109970/passing-member-function-pointer-to-the-c-style-function

Comment: @BryanFok that's about the best answer you are likely to get for the problem. Of course this leaves you the problem of how you get your object into the callback function, but the API didn't give you any hope of tracking instances from the looks of it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf put it to the answer plz